# Typo3 DCE - Align two or more fields side by side in the backend?

Tags: typo3, backend, tx-dce

I have a problem with the DCE extension in typo3. Basically, I have the necessity to put some fields of the same argument side by side in the backend so my component doesn't get too long. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible because of TYPO3 and not DCE. When you create a DCE element, the fields are saved as FlexForm in the **pi_flexform** column in **tt_content** table.

With normal TCAs you would be able to achieve this with **palettes**. But with FlexForm, sadly it is not possible to do it.

If you have the time and the willingness to create your own Content Elements with TYPO3 API, then here you go. If you have any question, you can ask me directly. [How to create TYPO3 custom content elements](https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

Best regards

Comment: Thank you! I'll try making my custom content element, then.